# Material table angular mat list

Tags: css, angular

I have this code here, which works perfectly, and when you click on the magnifying glass it opens some information:

```
 <mat-card *ngIf="(bills && bills.length > 0) && all"  style="overflow-x: auto;">
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-card *ngFor="let bill of bills; let i = index;" style="margin-top:1%; margin-bottom: 1%;">
          <mat-card-content>
            <mat-list role="list">
              <mat-list-item role="listitem" [ngClass]="{'section-active': bill.open, 'section':!bill.open}">
                <table style="table-layout: fixed;"> 
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th style="width:7%">{{ 'fields.registrationDate' | translate }}</th>
                      <th style="width:10%">{{ 'fields.favored' | translate }}</th>
                      <th style="width:18%">{{ 'fields.descritive' | translate }}</th>
                      <th style="width:10%"> {{ 'fields.generatedIn' | translate }}</th>
                      <th style="width:6%">{{ 'fields.invoiceNumber' | translate }}</th>
                      <th style="width:5%">{{ 'fields.portions' | translate }}</th>
                      <th style="width:5%">Status</th>
                      <th style="width:8%">{{ 'fields.value' | translate }}</th>
                      <th style="width:8%">{{ 'fields.realizedValue' | translate }}</th>
                      <th style="width:7" >{{ 'fields.nextMaturity' | translate }}</th>
                      <th style="width:15%">{{ 'fields.actions' | translate }}</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr >
                      <td style="width:5%;"  style="font-size: 12.5px;">{{ bill.dateInsert | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
                      <td style="font-size: 12.5px;" class="td10" [matTooltip]="bill.provider.name" >{{ bill.provider.name | limitTo: 22 }}</td>
                      <td style="font-size: 12.5px;" class="td22" [matTooltip]="bill.description">{{ bill.description | limitTo: 44  }}</td>
                      <td style="font-size: 12.5px;" class="td10"> {{ bill.generatedIn }}
                      <td style="width:3%;font-size: 12.5px;" >{{ bill.invoiceNumber }}</td>
                      <td style="width:5%;font-size: 12.5px;" >{{ bill.billInstallments.length }}</td>
                      <td style="width:5%;font-size: 12.5px;"  *ngIf="bill.isPaid === true">
                        {{ 'fields.paid' | translate }}
                      </td>
                      <td style="width:5%;font-size: 12.5px;"  *ngIf="bill.isPaid === false">
                        {{ 'fields.unpaid' | translate }}
                      </td>
                      <td style="width:8%"  style="font-size: 12.5px;">
                        {{ bill.value | currency: bill.currency }}
                      </td>
                      <td style="width:8%"  style="font-size: 12.5px;" [ngStyle]="(bill.value < bill.valueRealized) && bill.isPaid ? {'color': 'red'} : (bill.value > bill.valueRealized) && bill.isPaid ? {'color': 'green'} : {'color': 'black'}">
                        {{ bill.valueRealized | currency: bill.currency }}
                       </td>
                       <td style="width:5%"  style="font-size: 12.5px;" *ngIf="bill.isPaid === true">{{ '-' }}</td>
                       <td style="width:5%"  style="font-size: 12.5px;" *ngIf="bill.isPaid === false">{{ bill.nextMaturity | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                      <td class="p-10"  style="font-size: 19px;">
                        <div class="row">
                        <button mat-icon-button type="button" class="btn__view mr-1" (click)="toggleSection(i, bill)"
                          matTooltip="{{ 'button.view-parcels' | translate | uppercase }}">
                          <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        <a *ngIf="(!allConstruction || bill.investor)">
                        <button *hasClaim="'MENU_BILLEXPENSE_WRITE'" mat-icon-button type="button"
                          class="btn__edit mr-1" (click)="handleEditItem(bill)"
                          matTooltip="{{ 'button.edit' | translate | uppercase }}">
                          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        <button *hasClaim="'MENU_BILLEXPENSE_DELETE'" mat-icon-button type="button" class="btn__delete  mr-1"
                          (click)="handleRemoveItem(bill)" matTooltip="{{ 'button.delete' | translate | uppercase }}">
                          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </mat-list-item>
              <span class="child-list">
                <mat-card *ngIf="bill && bill.open" style="margin-top:3%; margin-left:40%; margin-bottom: 1%;">
                  <!--        <mat-card-subtitle>
                    {{ 'fields.portions' | translate }}
                  </mat-card-subtitle> -->
                  <mat-card-content>
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>{{ 'fields.portions' | translate }}</th>
                          <th>Status</th>
                          <th>{{ 'fields.dueDate' | translate }}</th>
                          <th>{{ 'fields.paymentDate' | translate }}</th>
                          <th>{{ 'fields.foreseenValue' | translate }}</th>
                          <th>{{ 'fields.realizedValue' | translate}}</th>
                          <th>{{ 'fields.actions' | translate }}</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let billInstallments of bill.billInstallments; let j = index;">
                          <td>{{j+1}}</td>
                          <td *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid === true">
                            {{ 'fields.paid' | translate }}
                          </td>
                          <td *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid === false">
                            {{ 'fields.unpaid' | translate }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ billInstallments.dueDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
                          </td>
                          <td *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid === true" [ngStyle]="(billInstallments.dueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy') < (billInstallments.paymentDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy') ? {'color': 'red'} : {'color': 'black'}">
                            {{ billInstallments.paymentDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
                          </td>
                          <td style="text-align: center;" *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid === false">
                            {{ '-' }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            {{ billInstallments.expectedValue | currency: bill.currency}}
                          </td>
                          <td [ngStyle]="billInstallments.expectedValue < billInstallments.realizedValue ? {'color': 'red'} : billInstallments.expectedValue > billInstallments.realizedValue && billInstallments.isPaid ? {'color': 'green'} : {'color': 'black'}">
                            {{ billInstallments.realizedValue | currency: bill.currency}}
                          </td>
                          <td class="p-10">
                            <span *hasClaim="'MENU_BILLEXPENSE_WRITE'" >
                              <button *ngIf="billInstallments.late === true && !billInstallments.isPaid" [disabled]="allConstruction && (bill.appropriate == true && !bill.investor)"  mat-icon-button type="button"
                                class="btnBillsLate mr-1" (click)="handleLower(bill,j)"
                                matTooltip="{{ 'button.lower' | translate | uppercase }}">
                                <mat-icon>monetization_on</mat-icon>
                              </button>
                              <button *ngIf="billInstallments.late === false && !billInstallments.isPaid" [disabled]="allConstruction && (bill.appropriate == true && !bill.investor)" mat-icon-button type="button"
                                class="btnBillsInDay mr-1" (click)="handleLower(bill,j)"
                                matTooltip="{{ 'button.lower' | translate | uppercase }}">
                                <mat-icon>monetization_on</mat-icon>
                              </button>
                              <button *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid" [disabled]="billInstallments.isPaid"  mat-icon-button type="button"
                              class="btnBillsPay mr-1" (click)="handleLower(bill,j)"
                              matTooltip="{{ 'button.lower' | translate | uppercase }}">
                              <mat-icon>monetization_on</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                            </span>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </mat-card-content>
                </mat-card>
              </span>
            </mat-list>
          </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

[image]

Only now I need to appear the title of the table only once, and not repeating according to the whole line.however no way I can, works correctly, because I need to continue by clicking expand the data, depending on the image.

I tried something like below, but everything was misconfigured

```
 <mat-card *ngIf="(bills && bills.length > 0) && all"  style="overflow-x: auto;">
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-card  style="margin-top:1%; margin-bottom: 1%;">
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-list role="list">
            <table  style="table-layout: fixed;"> 
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width:7%">{{ 'fields.registrationDate' | translate }}</th>
                  <th style="width:10%">{{ 'fields.favored' | translate }}</th>
                  <th style="width:18%">{{ 'fields.descritive' | translate }}</th>
                  <th style="width:10%"> {{ 'fields.generatedIn' | translate }}</th>
                  <th style="width:6%">{{ 'fields.invoiceNumber' | translate }}</th>
                  <th style="width:5%">{{ 'fields.portions' | translate }}</th>
                  <th style="width:5%">Status</th>
                  <th style="width:8%">{{ 'fields.value' | translate }}</th>
                  <th style="width:8%">{{ 'fields.realizedValue' | translate }}</th>
                  <th style="width:7" >{{ 'fields.nextMaturity' | translate }}</th>
                  <th style="width:15%">{{ 'fields.actions' | translate }}</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let bill of bills; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'section-active': bill.open, 'section':!bill.open}">
                <tr>
                  <td style="min-width:25%;"  style="font-size: 12.5px;">{{ bill.dateInsert | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
                  <td style="font-size: 12.5px;" class="td10" [matTooltip]="bill.provider.name" >{{ bill.provider.name | limitTo: 22 }}</td>
                  <td style="font-size: 12.5px;" class="td22" [matTooltip]="bill.description">{{ bill.description | limitTo: 44  }}</td>
                  <td style="font-size: 12.5px;" class="td10"> {{ bill.generatedIn }}
                  <td style="width:3%;font-size: 12.5px;" >{{ bill.invoiceNumber }}</td>
                  <td style="width:5%;font-size: 12.5px;" >{{ bill.billInstallments.length }}</td>
                  <td style="width:5%;font-size: 12.5px;"  *ngIf="bill.isPaid === true">
                    {{ 'fields.paid' | translate }}
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:5%;font-size: 12.5px;"  *ngIf="bill.isPaid === false">
                    {{ 'fields.unpaid' | translate }}
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:8%"  style="font-size: 12.5px;">
                    {{ bill.value | currency: bill.currency }}
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:8%"  style="font-size: 12.5px;" [ngStyle]="(bill.value < bill.valueRealized) && bill.isPaid ? {'color': 'red'} : (bill.value > bill.valueRealized) && bill.isPaid ? {'color': 'green'} : {'color': 'black'}">
                    {{ bill.valueRealized | currency: bill.currency }}
                   </td>
                   <td style="width:5%"  style="font-size: 12.5px;" *ngIf="bill.isPaid === true">{{ '-' }}</td>
                   <td style="width:5%"  style="font-size: 12.5px;" *ngIf="bill.isPaid === false">{{ bill.nextMaturity | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                  <td class="p-10"  style="font-size: 19px;">
                    <div class="row">
                    <button mat-icon-button type="button" class="btn__view mr-1" (click)="toggleSection(i, bill)"
                      matTooltip="{{ 'button.view-parcels' | translate | uppercase }}">
                      <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <a *ngIf="(!allConstruction || bill.investor)">
                    <button *hasClaim="'MENU_BILLEXPENSE_WRITE'" mat-icon-button type="button"
                      class="btn__edit mr-1" (click)="handleEditItem(bill)"
                      matTooltip="{{ 'button.edit' | translate | uppercase }}">
                      <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button *hasClaim="'MENU_BILLEXPENSE_DELETE'" mat-icon-button type="button" class="btn__delete  mr-1"
                      (click)="handleRemoveItem(bill)" matTooltip="{{ 'button.delete' | translate | uppercase }}">
                      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                  </a>
                </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </mat-list-item>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          <span class="child-list">
            <mat-card *ngIf="bill && bill.open" style="margin-top:3%; margin-left:40%; margin-bottom: 1%;">
              <!--        <mat-card-subtitle>
                {{ 'fields.portions' | translate }}
              </mat-card-subtitle> -->
              <mat-card-content>
                <table>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>{{ 'fields.portions' | translate }}</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>{{ 'fields.dueDate' | translate }}</th>
                      <th>{{ 'fields.paymentDate' | translate }}</th>
                      <th>{{ 'fields.foreseenValue' | translate }}</th>
                      <th>{{ 'fields.realizedValue' | translate}}</th>
                      <th>{{ 'fields.actions' | translate }}</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let billInstallments of bill.billInstallments; let j = index;">
                      <td>{{j+1}}</td>
                      <td *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid === true">
                        {{ 'fields.paid' | translate }}
                      </td>
                      <td *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid === false">
                        {{ 'fields.unpaid' | translate }}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{ billInstallments.dueDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
                      </td>
                      <td *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid === true" [ngStyle]="(billInstallments.dueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy') < (billInstallments.paymentDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy') ? {'color': 'red'} : {'color': 'black'}">
                        {{ billInstallments.paymentDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
                      </td>
                      <td style="text-align: center;" *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid === false">
                        {{ '-' }}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{ billInstallments.expectedValue | currency: bill.currency}}
                      </td>
                      <td [ngStyle]="billInstallments.expectedValue < billInstallments.realizedValue ? {'color': 'red'} : billInstallments.expectedValue > billInstallments.realizedValue && billInstallments.isPaid ? {'color': 'green'} : {'color': 'black'}">
                        {{ billInstallments.realizedValue | currency: bill.currency}}
                      </td>
                      <td class="p-10">
                        <span *hasClaim="'MENU_BILLEXPENSE_WRITE'" >
                          <button *ngIf="billInstallments.late === true && !billInstallments.isPaid" [disabled]="allConstruction && (bill.appropriate == true && !bill.investor)"  mat-icon-button type="button"
                            class="btnBillsLate mr-1" (click)="handleLower(bill,j)"
                            matTooltip="{{ 'button.lower' | translate | uppercase }}">
                            <mat-icon>monetization_on</mat-icon>
                          </button>
                          <button *ngIf="billInstallments.late === false && !billInstallments.isPaid" [disabled]="allConstruction && (bill.appropriate == true && !bill.investor)" mat-icon-button type="button"
                            class="btnBillsInDay mr-1" (click)="handleLower(bill,j)"
                            matTooltip="{{ 'button.lower' | translate | uppercase }}">
                            <mat-icon>monetization_on</mat-icon>
                          </button>
                          <button *ngIf="billInstallments.isPaid" [disabled]="billInstallments.isPaid"  mat-icon-button type="button"
                          class="btnBillsPay mr-1" (click)="handleLower(bill,j)"
                          matTooltip="{{ 'button.lower' | translate | uppercase }}">
                          <mat-icon>monetization_on</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                        </span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
          </span>
        </mat-list>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[image]

Comment: If you're using material angular, why not use a table with expandables row (the second example of https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve by adding this part in the code

```
<tr *ngIf="i == 0">
```